# Android Studio 3.0.1 Как добавить поддержку api 20 и ниже?

Tags: android, android-studio

Вопрос в заголовке. Android Studio 3.0.1 Как добавить поддержку api 20 и ниже в проложение?

Comment: установить в build.gradle minSdkVersion = , например 16? или раскройте свою проблему подробнее, что менно мешает вам установить поддержку апи меньше 20.

Answer (score 0):

В build gradle `(build.gradle(Module: app))` вашего приложения установите минимальную версию API

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"

        minSdkVersion 16 (Например 16)

        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Потом нажмите кнопку Sync gradle. Готово!